# python while loop asks for input twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

i am trying to learn about the while loop and am trying to build something with it.
i have a function that will hold a choice that the user will make but every time i run it the script is asking for the input twice..
can someone please explain to me what is wrong with my code? 
thanks in advance!! :)

code:

```
def choice():
    choice = int(input("what is your choice? "))
    valid_choice = False

    while not valid_choice:
        if choice >= 1 and choice <= 4:
            return choice
            valid_choice = True
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid response..")
            choice = int(input("what is your choice? "))
```

Comment: How do you run your code? I can reproduce this in my python console without the input being displayed twice.

Comment: Can you please show how you are calling the script?  I just ran it in Jupyter Notebook and only getting prompted once.

Comment: no it doesn't... i ran the function and it only ask once, if you get the number correct. If you get it wrong it would ask again tho

Comment: def beginning():
    while True:
        display_menu()
        choice()
        choose = choice()
        if choose == 1:
            print("Your status")
            print(Michael.status())
            print()
            print("Banks's status:")
            print(Prod.status())
        elif choose == 2:
            withraw = float(input("How much money do you want to withraw from the bank?: "))
            Prod.withrawl(withraw)
            Michael.withraw(withraw)

Comment: Please **update your question** with the content of your most recent comment.  Thanks!

Comment: you are calling choice twice

Comment: You need to edit that code into the question (so that it's actually readable), but it looks like you have two calls to `choice()` in a row - what did you expect would happen?

Comment: Strange enough, calling a function twice leads to the function being executed twice...

Answer (score 1):

```py
def beginning(): 
    while True: 
        display_menu()
        choose = choice()
        if choose == 1: print("Your status")
        print(Michael.status())
        print()
        print("Banks's status:")
        print(Prod.status()) elif choose == 2: withraw = float(input("How much money do you want to withraw from the bank?: "))
        Prod.withrawl(withraw)
        Michael.withraw(withraw)
```

You were calling choice twice

Comment: can you accept my answer please. Ya boi is trynna get some points

Comment: You might want to fix the indentation errors first.